# How to pass in EF Type names into method arguments?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am using MVC3, EF4.1 and C#.

I am trying to use a generic method to update a property which exists in numerous Entity Types. Therefore I need to pass in the Type into the method as an argument. How can I do this please?

Some code:

```
    public Boolean CompleteTask()
    {
        PRV myCurrentRecord = db.Task.OfType<PRV>().Single(r => r.Id == myId);
        myCurrentRecord.IsComplete = true;
        if (db.SaveChanges() > 0)
            return true;
        else return false;
    }
```

In the above example "PRV" is "hardcoded". I would like to pass in different types that all have "IsComplete" as a property.

I am using TPH inheritance, and have just realised that I can just use the parent entity, ie:

```
Parent.IsComplete
```

Would be interested, however, to know how one passes in a type.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a [generic method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcad0zb.aspx) for this:

```
public Boolean CompleteTask<TEntity>()
{
    TEntity myCurrentRecord = db.Task.OfType<TEntity>().Single(r => r.Id == myId);
    myCurrentRecord.IsComplete = true;
    if (db.SaveChanges() > 0)
        return true;
    else return false;
}
```

You have to add a type constraint for `TEntity` to make sure it derives from your parent type which has an `IsComplete` property.

```
public Boolean CompleteTask<TEntity>() where TEntity : ParentType
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Thoughts generics might come in. Can you please show me an example of the calling code. Would it be "CompleteTask<PRV>();" ?

Comment: Yes, you can pass the name of the class as `TEntity` like you propose. I assume you also want to pass an id, so it will become:  `CompleteTask<PRV>(myId);` for example.

Comment: You're welcome. By the way, I just realized that you _have_ to use the type constraint for `TEntity`, so you can use the `IsCompleted` property. Also updated my answer.

Answer (score -2):

Try the following and let me know

```
public Boolean CompleteTask(Type t)
{
    t myCurrentRecord = db.Task.OfType<t>().Single(r => r.Id == myId);
    myCurrentRecord.IsComplete = true;
    if (db.SaveChanges() > 0)
        return true;
    else return false;
}
```

This can then be called as follows:

```
CompleteTask(typeof(EFType));
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Christian has a point. Where is "t" used? I would expect it to be instead of "PRV"? Is this correct? Would it work? Thanks.

Comment: @christiandev where ever you need the type that is passed in, let me edit it, I missed a part in his question

Comment: this wont work, you cant pass an instance of `Type` to a generic param