# Using Entity properties in LINQ queries when <T> used, Possible?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, linq

I am trying to use the generic  in a generic method like so:

```
public Boolean Eval<T>( )
{
 var firstOrDefault = db.Class.OfType<T>().FirstOrDefault();
}
```

All the s have common properties like "SupplierId", so one would normally do:

```
public Boolean Eval<T>( )
{
  var firstOrDefault = db.Class.OfType<T>().FirstOrDefault(r=>r.SupplierId == intSupplierId);
}
```

However intellisence will complain about this since it does not know that  contain a "SupplierId" property. Is it possible to do this? If so how?

Many thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to pass in EF Type names into method arguments?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18849814/how-to-pass-in-ef-type-names-into-method-arguments)

Comment: Henk, Thank you for this. I forgot about your great answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a where clause. Your supplier ID would need to exist in your base class.
Also all classes would need to extend from your base class. [Constraints on Type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx).

```
public Boolean Eval<T>() where T : MyBaseClass
{
    var firstOrDefault = db.Class.OfType<T>()
                                 .FirstOrDefault(r => r.SupplierId == intSupplierId);
}
```

```
class MyBaseClass
{
    public int SupplierId { get; set; }
}
```

```
class MyCustomClass : MyBaseClass
{
    //Extended class
}
```

---

Alternatively you can concrete this.

```
public Boolean Eval()
{
    var firstOrDefault = db.Class.OfType<MyClass>()
                                 .FirstOrDefault(r => r.SupplierId == intSupplierId);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use generic type constraint:

```
public Boolean Eval<T>( ) where T : CommonClass
{
  var firstOrDefault = db.Class.OfType<T>()
                         .FirstOrDefault(r=>r.SupplierId == intSupplierId);
}
```